# How to add terms and condition checkbox in Yii user module?

Tags: php, checkbox, yii

I am new in implementing Yii user module.I want to add a checkbox for terms and conditions on registration page and I dont know how I can add it.

Could any one help me to add terms and conditions checkbox.I find a rule from Yii forum:

```
array('agree', 'required', 'requiredValue' => 1, 'message' => 'Please   accept Terms and Conditons.'),
```

But I dont know where this rule will be define means in which models or controller.

All the fields first name,last name, captcha code is already define only i need to add terms and conditions checkbox but its not working or how to enable agree feature.

Please Help me.

Comment: try to use activeCheckBox() method

Comment: Thanks Bo, but where i need to define rules for it.

Comment: look [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeCheckBox-detail)

Comment: I means i need to make some changes in model or controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I have find solution for it...

You need to add rules inside registration module's

```
YumRegistrationForm model.
```

and define rule inside rule function as:

```
$rules[] = array('agree', 'required',
    'requiredValue' => 1,
    'message' => Yum::t("Please accept Terms and Conditons."));
```

I have tried it and its work for me.. and in view You need to add check box as i have added:

```
<?php echo $activeform->checkBox($form, 'agree', array('class' => 'mR'));?>
   Terms &amp; condition
```

For that if you are using $form as i was using then you need to define agree variable as :

```
public $agree; inside YumRegistrationForm;
```

Thanks :-)